# How to avoid electron app shows js error popup on the screen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In chrome, using --kiosk flag can be avoid js error popup on browser.
but electron still shows js error even using setKiosk(true) to set kiosk mode.

need to know how to avoid electron shows popup that js error occures in browserWindow.

Comment: Added this in to js application would be loads into electron application, but still shows js error popup.      window.onerror=function(){ return true;}

Answer (score 0):

Use [trycatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) for example :

```
try {
  //  code  maybe will lead to an error

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you ＠YAGOUBI A.E.K, In this wrapper container app loads other peoples code, so I do not know where could be leads error. so need electron do not shows error popup, just silently freeze if error does not continue.